# Metrically bounded equivalent to order bounded for $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subset X$. Suppose there exists
> $0<b$ such that $$(\forall y)(\forall y')(y\in Y\land y'\in Y\implies
> > d(y,y')\leq b).$$ Then $Y$ is said to be **bounded in $X$ w.r.t. the
> metric $d$**.

Consider $\mathbf{R}$ together with its natural metric and let $Y\subset\mathbf{R}$. Then $Y$ is bounded in $\mathbf{R}$ w.r.t. $|-|$ if and only if there exists $0<r$ such that
$$(\forall y)(y\in Y\implies|y|\leq r).$$

**Attempt:**

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose we have an $0<r$ such that $|y|\leq r$ for all $y\in Y$. Let $y,y'\in Y$. Then
$$|y-y'|=|y+(-y')|\leq|y|+|-y'|=|y|+|y'|\leq 2r.$$

$\Rightarrow$: By definition there exists some $0<b$ such that $|y-y'|\leq b$ for all $y,y'\in Y$. I basically need an $r$ strictly greater than zero for which
$$-r\leq y\leq r$$
holds for all $y\in Y$. I am not sure how to find one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is the empty set then any $r > 0$ does the job.

Otherwise choose an arbitrary $y' \in Y$. Then
$$
 |y| = |y-y' + y'| \le |y-y'| + |y'| \le b + |y'|
$$
for all $y \in Y$, i.e. you can choose $r = b + |y'|$.